# Is Jetty 9.4.43 is affected by the Log4j2 vulnerabilities : CVE-2021-44228 or CVE-2021-45046 or CVE-2021-45105?

Tags: jetty

We are using jetty9.4.43 in our application.
Logging modules not being used by default.

Can any one confirm whether jetty9.4.43 has any impact over CVE-2021-44228?

Answer (score 2):

**Update: Dec 18, 2021**

There is a new Log4j CVE just issued.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html#CVE-2021-45105

Minimum recommended Log4j version is now 2.17.0.

**Update: Dec 13, 2021**

There is a new Log4J CVE issued.
https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2021-45046

Minimum recommended Log4j version is now 2.16.0

**Original Text**

Also covered at https://webtide.com/jetty-log4j2-exploit-cve-2021-44228/

Jetty has no direct dependency on log4j.

Jetty 9.x uses it's own logging framework `StdErrLog`, and has optional support for `slf4j`.

You, as a consumer of Jetty, can choose to use `slf4j` and then optionally take the next step and use log4j within that `slf4j` configuration.

So, while it's possible to use log4j 1.x or 2.x on Jetty 9.x, it's a decision that users choose to make, and it's up to the users to decide what they want to do.  (Eg: upgrade to log4j 2.16.0 to satisfy both recent CVEs, or switch to a different logging framework like logback)

Waiting for a new release of Jetty is not necessary to address this CVE.

Also note that the log4j2 CVE does not impact users on Java 11.0.2 or newer, as the internal JVM property `com.sun.jndi.ldap.object.trustURLCodebase` is set to false by default starting with Java 11.0.2, which disables JNDI loading of classes from arbitrary URL code bases.  (Users on Java 8 have more work than users on Java 11.0.2 or newer)

**Eclipse Jetty Security Reports**

All verified security reports for Eclipse Jetty can be found at ...

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/security_reports.php

Github tracked and published advisories can be found at ...

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/security/advisories?state=published

Comment: Hi @joakim-erdfelt does this `CVE-2021-42013` have any impact on jetty? We are using Jetty-9.4.38 and the client has run some scanner and informed us about CVE-2021-44228 & CVE-2021-42013. After which I did a little googling and came across this https://twitter.com/pwntester/status/1445486763577724942 
My confusion is this..we are not using Apache server then where from this is reported.
Can you provide some information about it?

Comment: The issue is entirely within log4j2.  If you are using log4j then you need to update that component.  There is no need to update Jetty to address the log4j CVEs.  (This is because Jetty does not depend on, ship, deploy, or use log4j)

Comment: @devd CVE-2021-42013 is not a log4j CVE.

Comment: 'CVE-2021-42013 is not a log4j CVE' that I understand, but can similar issue happen in Jetty.